# Qual a diferença entre o gráfico de barras e colunas no R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de saber a diferença prática entre os gráficos de barra e coluna, pois vejo no `ggplot` por exemplo que existem os comandos `geom_bar` e `geom_col`. Qual seria melhor ou quais as limitação de cada um?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível obter os mesmos resultados usando `geom_bar` e `geom_col`. As sintaxes dos comandos serão diferentes, mas esteticamente é possível obter exatamente o mesmo resultado gráfico.

`geom_bar` deixa a altura (ou comprimento, se forem barras horizontais) das barras proporcionais ao número de casos em cada grupo (a não ser que o parâmetro `weight` seja utilizado, mas aí é outra história). Ou seja, por padrão, `geom_bar` usa `stat_count()` para determinar o tamanho das barras.

`geom_col` é usado quando queremos que as barras representem valores diretamente presentes no conjunto de dados. Por padrão, `geom_col` usa `stat_identity()` para determinar o tamanho das barras.

Na prática, isso significa que `geom_bar` fará diretamente um gráfico de barras representando a frequência de alguma variável categórica presente no conjunto de dados. Para obter o mesmo resultado com `geom_col` é necessário pré-processar os dados, encontrando primeiramente essas frequências.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = drv)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = "geom_bar")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = drv)) +
  geom_col()
#> Error: geom_col requires the following missing aesthetics: y

mpg %>%
  group_by(drv) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = drv, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(y = "count", title = "geom_col")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

A escolha da utilização de cada método vai depender de cada usuário. Eu prefiro `geom_col`, mesmo ele dando um pouco mais de trabalho, pois consigo ver direitinho qual é a tabela de contagens que está sendo plotada.